# comparing a url containing utf-8 encoded string with a string

Tags: utf-8, hive

I have a url

```
"/complete/search?nolabels=t&client=chrome&ds=yt&q=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80&hl=ru"
```

and a list of key words. I need to determine if the url contains any of those words.

I checked this string `%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80`
using 
[utf-8 encoder](https://mothereff.in/utf-8)
thought I had to change `%` to `\x` for it to work.

I try using regular expressions for this

```
select "/complete/search?nolabels=t&client=chrome&ds=yt&q=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80&hl=ru" rlike encode("это рэп импр", "UTF-8");
```

but it doesn't accept a binary as an argument and `base64(encode("это рэп импр", "UTF-8"))` doesn't return the type of string I need.

My question is, how do I turn this `это рэп импр` into this `%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this

```
SELECT reflect("java.net.URLDecoder", "decode", "/complete/search?nolabels=t&client=chrome&ds=yt&q=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80&hl=ru", "UTF-8");
```